# How do I use ajax to upload a text field and a file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I'm new at AJAX and am working on an implementation of a form that will upload a name and a file to a php file that processes the data and sends it to a database for insertion using mysqli. I've tested the php file and it does work. My problem is in the AJAX code. I've tried an implementation using XMLHTTP and using jQuery. Both leave the page and open the PHP file in the browser. As a disclamer, I posted this question to another coding site, a fight ensued between two posters, and so I'm trying here to hopefully get a reasoned and calm response with productive suggestions.

I realize that currently "get" is being sent to the PHP file rather than "post", but PHPStorm tells me that "post" is not available in that form. What's my alternative? Am I on the right track or is there another direction I should go? How do I refresh only the form and keep the PHP page from loading?

Here's the relevant snippet of my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addForm').validate({

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    $('input[name="usingAJAX"]', this).val('true');
                    var url = $(form).prop('action');
                    var dataToSend = $(form).serialize();
                    var callback = function(dataReceived) {
                        $(form).hide();
                        //result message
                        $('body').append(dataReceived)
                    };
                    var typeOfDataToReceive = 'html';

                    $.get(url, dataToSend, callback, typeOfDataToReceive),
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="addForm" action="addInfo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="usingAJAX" value="false"/>
    <label for="aname">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="aname" id="aname" class=required/>
    <label for="aimage">Photo: </label>
    <input id="aimage" type="file" name="aimage" class="required">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot upload files using AJAX. Common workaround is to post form to a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Until recently you could not upload files with ajax.

You still cannot upload the file directly with ajax, but you can do it programatically with HTML5 File API.

Still, if you are looking for simple solutions, try traditional IFrame approach.

If you want bleading edge technology, use File API. Here is some [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) how to read files with javascript.

The steps to upload with ajax:

1. Read file with javascript FileReader API.
2. Post the content of the file, encoded to base64 or something, to the server.
3. Serverside, decode the contents of the file programatically.

When using this approach, the file will not be handled as a file upload by the server. It will be just another request field with text inside. It is up to you to decode it on the server side.

The filereader API allows you to read the file portion by portion and upload fragments of file, so it would be possible to upload huge files in chunks, but you need to handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using plugin jQuery form.js http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload You can upload files with ajax and jQuery. It is easy to use, just need to give `#form-id` in ajaxSubmit function.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#addForm').validate({

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $('input[name="usingAJAX"]', this).val('true');
                var options = {
                   url : $(form).prop('action'),
                   dataToSend : $(form).serialize(),
                   callback : function(dataReceived) {
                    $(form).hide();
                    //result message
                    $('body').append(dataReceived) },
                   typeOfDataToReceive = 'html';
                     //your options here 
               };

               $('#yourFormid').ajaxSubmit(options);

                return false;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```